# How to retrive a file from a prompt?

Tags: shell-script

Suppose I wanted to create a script that would prompt for a file to be search for.

Such that,

```
echo "What file are you searching for?"
read filename
filepath=/test/dir1
file=$filename
for I in file
do
echo "$I"
find "$filepath" "$I"
done
```

This seems to do a continual search for the filename specified. However, I get a **find: file: No such file or directory**

Comment: You say “retrieve a file”, “prompt for a file”, and “What file …”.   Are you talking about ***a*** file (or filename) or a list of them?  If just one, why are you using `for … in`?  That’s a loop construct, used for doing something multiple times (with different values).

Comment: I am not sure, however, I think I wanted to have each filename in file to be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `for I in file` should probably be `for I in $file`; the
dollar sign is needed when retrieving a variable's value.

I would alter your script in the following ways:

```
echo "What file names are you searching for?"
read files
filepath=/test/dir1

for f in $files
do
    echo "$f"
    find "$filepath"/"$f"
done
```

I removed the assignment to `$file` from `$filenames`, and assumed you
meant for the user to enter several whitespace-separated file names.

Then I passed `find` a single path, constructed by separating the
directory name and the file name with a single slash. If you meant to
look for a file named like this at an arbitrary depth, you may use `find
"$filepath" -name "$f"`.